# VB script to check if the file size has been increased from the previous check

Tags: vbscript

i need a VB script that checks the file size and captures it and in the next check it compares it with the previous check. If the size has increased, it should prompt File size increased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a try to this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
const bytesToKb = 1024
Dim strFile,Title
Title = "The File Size Checker by Hackoo 2015"
strFile = "C:\test.txt"
Call CheckSize(strFile)
'*****************************************************************
Sub CheckSize(File)
    Dim ws,fso,objFile,ReadSize,WriteSize,MySizeFile,Temp,LastSize
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    MySizeFile = Temp & "\MyFileSize.txt"
    If Not fso.FileExists(MySizeFile) Then
        Set WriteSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,2,True)
        set objFile = fso.GetFile(strFile)
        WriteSize.Write objFile.Size
    End If
    Set ReadSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,1)
    LastSize = ReadSize.readall
    set objFile = fso.GetFile(strFile)
    If CLng(objFile.Size) = CLng(LastSize) Then 
    MsgBox "There is no change on file size : " & CLng(LastSize) & " bytes" & vbcr &_
    "Size in Kb : "& CLng(objFile.Size/bytesToKb) & " Kb",VbInformation,Title
    else
    Set WriteSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,2,True)
        MsgBox "Last File Size is : " & CLng(LastSize) & " bytes" & vbcr &_
        "New File Size is : " & objFile.Size & " bytes" & vbcr &_
        "Size in Kb : "& CLng(objFile.Size/bytesToKb) & " Kb",VbExclamation,Title
    WriteSize.Write objFile.Size 
    end if
End Sub 
'*******************************************************************
```

I improved a little this script to check every minute in a loop if the size was changed or not, if yes it will popup a msgbox to notify you that size was changed, if no, it sleeps for 1 minute and it checks it again.

```
Option Explicit
const bytesToKb = 1024
Dim strFile,Title
Title = "The File Size Checker by Hackoo 2015"
strFile = "C:\test.txt"
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding",VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else   
    Do   
        Call CheckSize(strFile)
    Loop   
End If 
'*****************************************************************
Sub CheckSize(File)
    Dim ws,fso,objFile,ReadSize,WriteSize,MySizeFile,Temp,LastSize
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    MySizeFile = Temp & "\MyFileSize.txt"
    If Not fso.FileExists(MySizeFile) Then
        Set WriteSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,2,True)
        set objFile = fso.GetFile(strFile)
        WriteSize.Write objFile.Size
    End If
    Set ReadSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,1)
    LastSize = ReadSize.readall
    set objFile = fso.GetFile(strFile)
    If CLng(objFile.Size) = CLng(LastSize) Then 
        Call Pause(1) 'To sleep for 1 minute
    else
    Set WriteSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,2,True)
        MsgBox strFile & vbcr &"Last Size is : " & CLng(LastSize) & " bytes" & vbcr &_
        "New Size is : " & objFile.Size & " bytes" & vbcr &_
        "Size in Kb : "& CLng(objFile.Size/bytesToKb) & " Kb",VbExclamation,Title
    WriteSize.Write objFile.Size 
    end if
End Sub 
'**************************************************************************
'Checks whether a script with the same name as this script is already running
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
        " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
```

Here is another approch that can monitor and check more than one file in changing size :

```
Option Explicit
const bytesToKb = 1024
Dim Title,strFile,ListFiles
Title = "The File Size Checker by Hackoo 2015"
ListFiles = Array("c:\test.txt","E:\My test dossier\t.txt","E:\My test dossier\TmpLog.txt")
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding",VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else   
    Do   
        Call Main(ListFiles)
        Call Pause(1) 'To Sleep for 1 minute
    Loop   
End If 
'******************************************************************
Sub Main(strFilesPaths)   
    Dim strFile   
    For Each strFile In strFilesPaths     
        CheckSize(strFile)   
    Next   
End Sub   
'******************************************************************
Function StripPath(Path)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(Path,"\")   
    StripPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'*****************************************************************
Sub CheckSize(File)
    Dim ws,fso,objFile,ReadSize,WriteSize,MySizeFile,Temp,LastSize,strFile
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    For Each strFile In ListFiles 
        MySizeFile = Temp & "\" & StripPath(strFile)
        If Not fso.FileExists(MySizeFile) Then
            Set WriteSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,2,True)
            set objFile = fso.GetFile(strFile)
            WriteSize.Write objFile.Size
        End If
        Set ReadSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,1)
        LastSize = ReadSize.readall
        set objFile = fso.GetFile(strFile)
        If CLng(objFile.Size) = CLng(LastSize) Then 
        else
            Set WriteSize = fso.OpenTextFile(MySizeFile,2,True)
            MsgBox strFile & vbcr &"Last Size is : " & CLng(LastSize) & " bytes" & vbcr &_
            "New Size is : " & objFile.Size & " bytes" & vbcr &_
            "Size in Kb : "& CLng(objFile.Size/bytesToKb) & " Kb",VbExclamation,Title
            WriteSize.Write objFile.Size 
        end if
    Next
End Sub 
'**************************************************************************
'Checks whether a script with the same name as this script is already running
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
```