# How to get the file size of any file type using VBScript even if the file name is modified?

Tags: vbscript

I just started using VBScript today and I'm attempting to get the file size of any file type. My script only returns the file size of the file name provided, but if the file name changes, it renders an error: "file not found"

Here is the script:

```
CONST bytesToKb = 1024
strFile = "X:\My Docs\Reports\Report1.txt"

SET objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SET objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFile)

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine CINT(objFile.Size / bytesToKb)
```

how can I modify the second line to accept any file name, in case the file name Report1.txt is changed to demo.txt? The path to the file will remain the same, just the file name will change. ...Thanks in advance

Comment: How do yo want to input, select, provide, specify the file to check, that is the question.

Comment: Since the file will be manually placed into a directory, so the file will already be in place, I just need to return the size of the file. The script above returns the file size, but if/when the file is renamed, I just need the script to handle that. Be able to return the size of the file still, even after it's been renamed. ...thanks

Comment: but how can your script knows which file it is if it was renamed??? It can only work if there's only one file in the directory, the one that was renamed. But if it is the case you would better to clearly state it in the question because that's the most important thing to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB script to check if the file size has been increased from the previous check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298946/vb-script-to-check-if-the-file-size-has-been-increased-from-the-previous-check)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix your Main Folder and check all files on it by a loop :

```
Const bytesToKb = 1024
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MainFolder = "E:\TestFolder"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MainFolder)
For each objFile in objFolder.Files
    wscript.echo objFile.Name & vbTab & CINT(objFile.Size/bytesToKb) & " kb"
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I required. Your assist was greatly appreciated.